Questions regarding Tag Helpers and View Components
First of all I will start by apologizing for a messy question.
So I have been fiddling around with custom tag helpers and I need your thoughts. So far I've only extended simple tags like buttons and inputs with additional tag helper attributes in order to style the tags with desirable Tailwind CSS classes and other bits. This works nicely but now I'm trying to wrap my head around more complex components that also involves nested components.
Lets take a dropdown component as an example. So since we are using Tailwind CSS for styling and Alipne JS for client manipulation I would like for the "components" to be as straight forward to write in the views as possible and where the defined Tailwind classes and JS functionality is added "behind the scenes" of the component.
I will try to explain how I would like to be able use the dropdown component.
// Define dropdown component in a view
<dropdown-menu>

    // I would like to be able to define the dropdown "toggle" element from the
    // view since you might want to have different kind of tags for this 
    // purpose (button or span).
    // Also since I've already made custom attributes for some of the tags
    // (like the button) I want to be able to define these individually from the view         
    // where the dropdown is used. For example some dropdowns might have a "primary"
    // button style and some "default" or other custom attributes.
    // Then preferably from within the components view I would like to be able to add CSS 
    // classes and Alpin JS attributes to the passed "toggle" element.
    <button button-variant="primary" button-icon="dots" class="some-class">More</button>
    
    // The content of the dropdown should preferably also be set from the view and 
    // also be passed to the components view so these also could get set css classes and so on.
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test 1</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test 2</a>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test 3</a>
</dropdown-menu>

I've played around with Tag Helpers for this and I'm able to create a somewhat reasonable dropdown component that also has a partial view but I feel like its not flexible enough (or I might not understand the principles). The main thing that I don't find a good way of handling is the manipulation of the children of the tag helper. It involves a lot of string manipulation in order to change or update the content/children of the dropdown and I would preferably like to be able to do this from within the tag helper partial view since its much more easier to read.
Is there some way of creating a component (tag helper or view component) that is defined as a tag helper in the view and then pass the contents as objects to the components view in order to add/edit classes and other attributes on the dropdown toggle and dropdown content?

A whole working demo you could follow:
Custom Tag Helper
[HtmlTargetElement("dropdown-menu")]
public class DropdownMenuTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Wrap content with a div or any other necessary element
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "relative inline-block text-left");

        // Allow child Tag Helpers to add to this dictionary
        context.Items["DropdownToggleTag"] = "button";
        context.Items["DropdownMenuClass"] = "dropdown-content-class"; // Customize as needed

        // Add necessary classes or attributes for Alpine JS here
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("x-data", "{ open: false }");
    }
}
[HtmlTargetElement("dropdown-toggle")]
public class DropdownToggleTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string ButtonVariant { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var tagName = context.Items["DropdownToggleTag"].ToString();
        output.TagName = tagName;

        var classes = "px-4 py-2";
        if (ButtonVariant == "primary")
        {
            classes += " bg-blue-500 text-white";
        }

        // Add Alpine JS attributes for interactivity
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("@click", "open = !open");
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", classes);

    }
}
[HtmlTargetElement("dropdown-item", ParentTag = "dropdown-menu")]
public class DropdownItemTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string AspController { get; set; }
    public string AspAction { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // Set the tag to a link or button based on the context
        output.TagName = "a";

        // Build the link with Razor URL helpers (optional)
        var href = $"/{AspController}/{AspAction}";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", href);

        // Apply default classes for dropdown items
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700");
        //Add necessary classes or attributes for Alpine JS here
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("x-show", "open");

    }
}

Use the Dropdown Component in a View
<dropdown-menu>
    <dropdown-toggle button-variant="primary">
        More
    </dropdown-toggle>
    <dropdown-item asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test 1</dropdown-item>
    <dropdown-item asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test 2</dropdown-item>
    <dropdown-item asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Test 3</dropdown-item>
</dropdown-menu>

To make the Custom TagHelper class available to all our Razor views, add the addTagHelper directive to the Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file:
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, {YourAssemblyName}

Import Tailwind CSS and Alpine JS refrence in _Layout.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css">

</head>
<body>
     //...
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js" defer></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>


So this is what I managed to create by myself but I feel like the way the tags are manipulated in the code, like adding attributes and so on is a bit messy when creating more complex tag helpers. What I ideally would like to do is to be able to pass the generated tags into a partial view so that it is more readable and manageable. To do this It looks like to only option would be to use a parser like HtmlAgilityPack.
I'm a bit hesitant to write code (C#) in order to create HTML, preferably I would like to write the HTML in plain HTML and not in another language.

Hi @David, a bit confused for your description. You do not want to create such complex custom tag helper with writing the html in it?  I dont understand what's the meaning of the custom tag helper if you do not write the html. Can you edit your question and share more details with us. Thank you.
